# Setting java home

Tags: java, android, linux

I'm trying to use the command "ant build".The message says `java home is not defined correctly we cannot execute /usr/bin/java//bin/java <notice the 2 slashes>`

If i use the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` it returns `usr/bin/java` . What needs changing here?

Comment: Check your ~/.bash_profile, likely $JAVA_HOME is defined there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$JAVA_HOME` variable does not refer to the java executable, but to the parent directory of the `bin/java` executable itself. This is the reason Ant complains of not being able to execute some cryptic `/usr/bin/java//bin/java`.

For example, in my case (Ubuntu 12.04, OpenJDK) the java home is set to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

where obviously there exists a `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`, of which `/usr/bin/java` ultimately represents a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Ant is assuming `/usr/bin/java` to start.  Perhaps you don't need to set it.

Or try adding a leading slash (`/usr` instead of `usr`).

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME shouldn't be pointed to the java executable, rather it should be the parent directory of 'bin' where javac the compiler is located.

Usually the '/usr/bin/java' is a symbolic link to the actual executable in somewhere else, e.g., '/usr/lib/java/jdk*/bin/java', in which case the java home should be /usr/lib/java/jdk*.