# export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL:etc/hadoop/

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop

While installing hadoop in pseudo distributed mode i was intially getting below error

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: namenode running as process 20678. Stop it first.
localhost: datanode running as process 20831. Stop it first.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established
```

by mistake i excecuted below command

```
hduser@x7158796-dsmprojb:/usr/local/hadoop$ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL:etc/hadoop/
hduser@x7158796-dsmprojb:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found
```

and now it's showing that java home is not set

I am new to linux can anybody help regarding this.?
.

Answer (score 0):

there area few examples here which you can find [Setting java home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970051/setting-java-home)

and there are a few ways of finding java home

on RedHat

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

then

```
export JAVA_HOME=<replace me with from above alteratives command>
```

either in your shell or add it to your .profile/.bashrc/etc